# How is the default list of questions that appears to viewers who are not logged-in populated?

Tags: bug, status-completed

Are the questions listed for someone who initially (without being a logged-in user) visits the SkepticsSE site selected purely by algorithm or is there human censorship?

Why does Mohammed's question about the former Iran leader not appear, despite being a recent, recently modified, upvoted, answered question?

[Did Ayatollah Ruhollah Khomeini, The Supreme Leader of Iran, say this about pedophilia?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/36138/did-ayatollah-ruhollah-khomeini-the-supreme-leader-of-iran-say-this-about-pedo)

Is this concealed by human censorship or status-by-design algorithm?

Comment: It *should be* the same as the active tab -- it clearly is not, we are investigating

Comment: @Sklivvz Thanks for checking on that.  This isn't the first time I noticed.  I think the same was true for this question: http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/34743/do-42-of-young-muslims-in-france-support-suicide-bombings/36130#36130 I can't think of any corresponding computer-implementable algorithm, seems to pass Turing test.

Comment: @ff524 that's only on SO

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's showing the *active* questions filtered by the top 10 tags on the site. In our case: [medical-science](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/medical-science)[united-states](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/united-states)[nutrition](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nutrition)[history](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/history)[biology](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/biology)[politics](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/politics)[psychology](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/psychology)[physiology](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/physiology)[economics](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/economics)[physics](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/physics).

I personally find it quite confusing: we're debating internally if and how to change it.

---

Update: we're changing it to unfiltered, no one really likes it as-is. It will be fixed in the next deployment.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.  The "united-states" factor seems especially discriminatory.  Hopefully this policy can be changed to avoid discriminating against any particular nationality, race, or religion.